# Views count for a question should not be raised higher when the question owner views it multiple times

Tags: feature-request, views

Views for a question should not be raised higher when the question owner views it multiple times. As a owner of the script I might review a question multiple times, but, if it raises the view count, I do not get a fair idea how much times it has been viewed by others or if someone else has interests into that question.

Comment: How do you know it does this?

Comment: I think its unique views, so as long as you keep looking from the same computer your view should only count once

Comment: @Richard - Agreed, probably that is what confusing me, as I checked after logging from another browser

Comment: Mostly I access the site from the same computer. Sometimes when I open my previous questions (which was not activated when viewing) it raise the count by 1. And this happens almost everytime (AFAIR).

Comment: wouldn't it be useful to categorize as Anonymous views and member views as well?

Comment: @prasun - No that's not a good idea (suggested in your comment). What's the point to differentiate it?

Comment: If I am viewing an answer to my question without being logged in and refresh it multiple times (refresh interval would atleast be 10 mins), the count would go higher

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have confirmed this, and it is very likely by design. There's no reason for SE to store the addresses of everyone who's ever viewed a question. Not only would that be a security problem, but it would also be an expensive query and take up a massive amount of disk space.

Very likely they cache the viewers' list for ~10 minutes, then dump it. That prevents people from refreshing repeatedly to increase views, but also keeps a more accurate view count. Remember, one person can view a question multiple times.

Comment: Thank you that answers it